# How to address an invalid "NOT IN ()" query?

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

## Symptoms:

In WordPress admin menu we cannot see any pages or products listed any more,
even thoguh the pages and products are still accessible through weblinks for example.

## Tracing the issue:

On one hand as far as I can see in query monitor is that an invalid empty array parameter is provided for **NOT IN()**:

 "`AND wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()`"
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax`
The caller line is long, seemingly it originates somewhere in WooCommerce or WooCommerce-payments plugins.
Unfortunately the problem does not go away if I disable such plugins (and most others also).

 The problem however DOES go away if I disable the i-excel THEME.

 Obviously I need the theme to be turned back on.

 it had no issues this far, and we did not update anything in the system really.
So I'm stuck in here.

### UPDATES:

So as stated the comments conversation, first I have traced the likeliness of the error to an auto-update of WordPress core from 5.9.2 to 6.3.2 (hu).
I have used a downgrade tool to restore the old version, but that did not solve anything. 
Then I have again updated back everything recently, not only WordPress put this time all plugins.
I still have this same error type, but only 2 occurrences in the log out of 5, and the site itself is thankfully still up and running. 
This is where I'm at, still hunting for the final solution.

### Updates 2:

I have traced down everything in the callstack.
up until "`get_option('wp_custom_filters');`"
I want to know what is/what is inside`wp_custom_filters`
to see if that can be amended on the user interface/database level maybe. I did not find anything about it in google yet.

```
function customFiltersSettings() {
    $settings = get_option('wp_custom_filters');

    if (!$settings) {
        return null;
    }

    return unserialize(base64_decode($settings));
}
```

There is a criterium for sending null if the list is empty,
and `wp_posts.post_author NOT IN (null)` would create no error,
but for some reason `wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()` runs instead at the end.

## Appendix

This is the shortest query error out of the 4 that I can see in query monitor:

```
    SELECT wp_posts.ID
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE 1=1
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_subscription'
    AND wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
```

The caller for that shows this:

```
    WP_Query->get_posts()
    wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3219
    WP_Query->query()
    wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3800
    WP_Query->__construct()
    wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3932
    WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT->query()
    wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php:965
    WC_Data_Store->__call()
    wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php:207
    WC_Order_Query->get_orders()
    wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-query.php:87
    wc_get_orders()
    wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php:66
    wcs_do_subscriptions_exist()
    wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/wcs-functions.php:62
    WC_Payments_Subscriptions_Empty_State_Manager->replace_subscriptions_empty_state()
    wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/includes/subscriptions/class-wc-payments-subscriptions-empty-state-manager.php:93
    apply_filters('woocommerce_subscriptions_not_found_label')
    wp-includes/plugin.php:205
    WC_Subscriptions_Core_Plugin->register_order_types()
    wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-core-plugin.php:341
    do_action('init')
    wp-includes/plugin.php:517
```

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint in the `get_posts` method and then step back through the execution?

Comment: @NicoHaase in chrome dev-tools, or what do you mean exactly?
If you can please provide step by step for this idea.

Comment: In a PHP debugger. Chrome is not the tool of choice here, as it only receives the generated markup

Comment: One furthe UPDATE: It seems that unfortuunately WordPress auto-updated itself recently to the latest release. That at least explains where the change comes from. What can be the next best steps knowing that?  Maybe rolling back to a backup and trying to turn aouto-updat off somehow?

Comment: It can be related to [WooCommerce HPOS](https://woocommerce.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/) orders feature that can be auto enabled since version 8.2, as WC_Subscription is extended from WC_Order. Is subscription plugin updated? What WooCommerce version are you using?

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I have added updates to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it eventually.
I suspect this was an injection attack on the system by a bot that managed to create a user account for itself.
One lesson learned is to govern user creation more strictly. 
But it's still not fully clear what/how the intruder acted, 
so if somebody has a clue, share in the comments please...

This is what I conlcluded and mitigated:
In the `AND wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()`, the `()` was receiving it's value from:

```
function customFiltersSettings() {
    $settings = get_option('wp_custom_filters');

    if (!$settings) {
        return null;
    }

    return unserialize(base64_decode($settings));
}
```

I looked up the database's wp_options table to see what the `wp_custom_filters` entry contains,
 and it contained 'YTowOnt9' a.k.a `a:0:{}` translated from base64. 
This way the `!$settings` protection could not replace the empty array with a suitable `null`, 
because at the time of checking it was a real value in base64.
**So simply deleting the content of `wp_custom_filters` entry in the `wp_options` table of the database, resolved the error.**

Theme/Plugin/WPDevelopers need to check, but I think this might be a live vulnerability in i-excel and also in twentytwenty theme I think. (maybe even more).

I would suggest a correction that would expand the `if !$settings` part with some extra code that also validates the decoded value of `unserialize(base64_decode($settings)` ...
What I don't know among many things yet is what wp_custom_filters originates from, and how can somebody from the UI modify it's content?! (eg. where was the intrusion point, AND where can I use this option for something actually useful.